# Cannot read-in matlab file into R

Tags: r, matlab

Totally new to `matlab` and cannot read-in a matlab file:

```
install.packages("R.matlab")
library(R.matlab)

xyz <- readMat("[My path]/File_Name.mat")
```

Error message:

```
Error in file(con, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, open = "rb") :
  cannot open file '[My path]/File_Name.mat': No such file or directory
```

Any help?

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit: the file does not exist. The string you pass to readMat must be an actual system path, e.g. something like "/home/chris/File_Name.mat" if the file File_Name.mat lies in directory /home/chris. If you are on Linux, character case matters, File_Name.mat is not the same as file_name.mat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm well aware of the issue you're addressing. `File_Name` is not actually the file's name etc. But what about the first part of the error: `Error in file(con, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection`?

Comment: Opening the connection in R means opening the file. It can't open the connection because the file does not exist. As the error message says. If you want more details, you will have to look at the source code, but obviously, to import a Matlab .mat file, you must fist open the file as binary, and that's what `file(con, open = "rb")` does.

Comment: You may also try the example in ?readMat to check that your installation does not have a problem.